# Find a manga about a boy who uses heavy hammer as weapon

Tags: croket

It's about a boy who have a hammer as a weapon, which is very heavy. His father died protecting hiim. The manga is about him having an adventure. He also has some companion. One of them has handsome face but small body and he has to wear a mask to hide that.

Answer (score 4):

It is crocket!. 
http://myanimelist.net/manga/17005/Croket!

I have found it after scanning 600 titles on myanimelist

Answer (score 0):

Is it [MÄR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%84R).

I have not read it but he do have some kind of hammer weapon

[image]

He seems to have quite a lot friends. But i can't find something about his dad.

Comment: I dont think so. The other main is younger and he uses a wood hammer. Thank you anyway